# responseText is returning the top of my php file

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a setup where I am using ajax to retrieve data from the database.  Right now I'm trying to nail down sending an array from the php file to the javascript where my ajax is run.

Currently I'm using json encode to send the data from the php file

`echo json_encode($send_array);`

And then I am trying to retrieve it as an array on the javascript side with a json parse on the response text.

```
JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
```

This is where it get's weird.  If I just print out or display xhttp.responseText, I get a text representation of my array.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

But if I run JSON.parse on it, I get an syntax error of an unexpected '<'.

Digging further, if I do  xhttp.responseText[0], it returns '<'.

Testing it further, I found xhttp.responseText[4] returns '@' which is the fourth character in the comment at the very top of my php file.

I need help figuring out why xhttp.responseText returns text in the correct format, but trying to retrieve only part of the responseText or trying to parse on it returns the top of my php file instead.

Comment: Just to confirm are you adjusting the content type?  `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: @LukePark yes, I have that at the top of my php in the php file.  Though I'm still not sure what that line does.

Comment: Try opening the developer console in your browser (F12) and check the response from the server (Network).

Comment: @Shashank The thing is, the php file creates the array by adding in the values one by one before it's json encoded and it displays correctly when simply xhttp.responseText is called in the javascript.  What's baffling me is why xhttp.responseText[0] wouldn't return 1 or even '[' at the very least.

Comment: @Streetlamp I think you're on to something.  The preview is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] but the response is <!--@
Ethan Fetsko
Data Table Page
Date: November 6, 2015
-->

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. 

So it looks like for some reason the header comment is being sent along with the array. Any ideas why?  My only echo statement is the one sending the json encoded array.

Comment: @Streetlamp So my php file had html style comments at the top.  It seems that those get sent for some reason along with whatever data I echo.  I was able to fix it by just removing those html style comments.  I can just have php styled comments instead I suppose.

Comment: @user3225440 That makes sense. JSON does not ignore HTML-style comments. Happy your problem is solved. Don't forget to edit your question to include what your problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Now Solved. It turns out the problem was that my php file had html styled comments at the top. These were getting send along with the data that was echoed.